# Why is Gradle trying to retrieve a jar from Gradle plugins that will never exist?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I am creating my own Gradle plugin and I am trying to figure out how this works. There is one thing I don't understand.

**Published artifacts**
When publishing you create two "parts" of your plugin: a pom file with the meta-data of the plugin and actual jar files (with poms) that contain the source. The pom file of the plugin has a very long artifactId, which is the groupId with .gradle.plugin attached.

**Spotbugs example**
To make it more clear I use the spotbugs plugin as an example. If you check the Gradle Plugin Portal, you can see that it has the following files:

- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/spotbugs/com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin/5.0.0-rc.1/com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin-5.0.0-rc.1.pom (this is the pom with meta data)
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/spotbugs/snom/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/5.0.0-rc.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-5.0.0-rc.1.jar (this is the actual code of the plugin)
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/spotbugs/snom/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/5.0.0-rc.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-5.0.0-rc.1.pom

**Gradle debug logging**
I have created an empty Gradle project and applied the spotbugs plugin:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("com.github.spotbugs") version "5.0.0-rc1"
}
```

Now I ran the command `gradle spotbugsMain --refresh-dependencies` and I checked the logging. Here I see this:

```
2021-11-25T09:24:52.570+0100 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: <artifactory-url>/com/github/spotbugs/com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin/5.0.0-rc.1/com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin-5.0.0-rc.1.jar]
```

**Question**
Why does it even try to retrieve `com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin-5.0.0-rc.1.jar`? I checked other plugins in the Gradle Plugin Portal. There is not a single plugin I could find that has such a jar. There is only a pom, refering to the actual plugin artifact.

My guess is that Gradle tries to retrieve an artifact with generic code, which by default tries to retrieve multiple files (pom/jar). However, that would be a waste of time it seems. I cannot find any good documentation on this technical side. Can there actually be such a jar? If so, what can it contain?

Comment: there is this open issue on Gradle side, which explains this behavior:  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8754